# 18.04 Remmina, remote desktop connection, best way?

Tags: xfce, connection, remote, remmina

I have 2 laptops with Ubuntu 18.04 with XFCE installed, on different networks (providers), locations are about 30 km distant.

SSH connection configured, no problem with connection to remote machine via SSH, because he has public address, on router forwarding configured.

What is the best and simplest way connect to remote desktop (X) to view activity of this remote desktop and make some changes? For case if somebody need do something on remote computer and best way is to show him how to do that on remote computer via remote connection from my home.

If I can connect via SSH, can I connect to this server to remote desktop (graphic evnironment, XFCE) of user only with SSH with command from terminal? Or from remmina? Or VNC or Teamviewer is needed?

And last question, what if IP address of the remote computer not be available? So only VNC or Teamviewer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `xrdp` and `xorgxrdp` which is giving a really good way to remotely connect on your computer. You can use Remmina and use rdp protocol so you just have to open the port 3389/tcp the same way you made it for ssh.

Comment: Thanks, I will. So it is working for case if user on remote computer is logged? No kick off from desktop? Will I see same screen as user? And will he see my work on his computer? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you cannot login on RDP if same user already logged on console as far as I remember.

Comment: Probably you are right, I tried everything, but it didn't work. Or maybe some bad configuration? Just install on remote computer and then just connect via RDP in remmina? Or some special configuration is needed? Or should I use some other applications, for example teamviewer, etc. Is there some better application? Thanks.